# Simple jQuery function not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

Basically, I've got an Ajax call which is returning data based on the **Ajax** request as such :

```
var thisId = jQuery(this).data("id");
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: pluginURL + "/****/templates/files/ajax_controller.php",
    data: "ajaxAction=AddId&id=" + thisId,
    success: function(data) {
        if(data === "success") {            
            var OldId = jQuery("input").find("[data-id='" + thisId + "']");
            if(OldId) {
                alert("Valid OldId!");
                OldId.val("Added!");
                OldId.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
    }
});
```

What's happening is the `alert()` is executing, just not the `val()` or the `attr` it's probably something very simple that i'm overlooking

Comment: find() method looks for descendants, not attributes. BTW, even an empty jquery object is true, your condition check will pass in any case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you've got this bit wrong.

```
var OldId = jQuery("input").find("[data-id='" + thisId + "']");
```

The above looks for elements matching `[data-id='" + thisId + "']` **inside** `<input>`s.

Try replacing it with:

```
var OldId = jQuery("input[data-id='" + thisId + "']");
```

---

Plus, as pointed out by user *roasted*, your `if` condition is incorrect. It should be:

```
if(OldId.length > 0) {
...
}
```

Comment: Ahh.. Typos typos.. Corrected. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`.val` and `.attr` execute, but they have nothing to do.

```js
jQuery("input").find("[data-id='" + thisId + "']")
```

This does not return anything, ie. the jQuery object will be empty.

```
if (OldId)
```

The jQuery object still evaluates as true, even if it's empty. One way to check for emptiness is `OldId.length === 0`. So if you want to check if a jQuery object has matched, use `jq.length > 0`.

Comment: Thanks for providing such positive criticism, I'll take note of this, Thanks!